# Is there a way to remove items from various lists based on conditional statements?

Tags: python, list

I am writing a program that will act as a photography idea-generator for New York photographers. The way it works now is quite simple, the code is utilizing the random.choice function to randomly pull items from lists, then the code prints them out in a way that forms a sentence in English as an end result.

My issue is I need to add some logic to this, as some results would not make sense for a photographer to do (at least in my opinion). In this example I am trying to remove 'Bracketed (HDR)' from the technique_list, IF "Portrait" happens to be randomly chosen when python chooses the theme item.

I have a feeling I am mis-using the .remove function within the conditional if statement. Is there a better way to do this? I have attached the pertinent parts of the code for examination.

I have tried technique_list.remove('Bracketed (HDR)') , as well as

del technique_list[0] , both as the response part of the if statement.

```
import random 

print ("You should try taking a...")

#pool of items that the program will randomly choose..
theme_list = ['Cityscape','Peoplescape','Port-Scape', 'Portrait']
technique_list  = ['Bracketed (HDR)','Wide Angle', 'Zoom','Long 
Exposure','Fast Shutter','Daytime Long Expo','Timelapse']


#what we need here are conditional IF statements,  that manipulate items 
from various lists

#this bit of code determines the theme of a photo idea
theme_var = random.choice(theme_list) 
for theme in theme_var:
if theme == 'Portrait':
        technique_list.remove('Bracketed (HDR)') 
print("",theme_var)

#this bit of code determines the technique of a photo idea
technique_var = random.choice(technique_list)
print("", technique_var)

print("picture, from")

#this line of code determines the location of a photo idea
location_var = random.choice(location_list)
print("", location_var)
```

This still remains one of the possible results of the code:

```
You should try taking a...
 Portrait
 Bracketed (HDR)
picture, from
 34th Street
during
 Sunrise
and then give it a
 Black & White
edit in Lightroom!
[Finished in 0.2
```

As I said earlier, Portrait and Bracketed (HDR) should never be part of the same result, it doesn't make sense for this situation.

Comment: Cool application! Can we correctly assume that for every theme you have a list of techniques with which they should not be combined? Can you make a dictionary `d_wrong_technique` where the keys are themes and the values are lists (possibly of zero length) containing inappropriate techniques for the specific theme?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with a dictionary of inappropriate techniques, a list comprehension, and top it off with an f-string:

```
import random 

#pool of items that the program will randomly choose..
theme_list = ['Cityscape','Peoplescape','Port-Scape', 'Portrait']
technique_list  = ['Bracketed (HDR)','Wide Angle', 'Zoom','Long Exposure','Fast 
Shutter','Daytime Long Expo','Timelapse']
location_list = ['34th Street']

# dictionary of inappropriate techniques for given theme
d_inappropes = {'Cityscape': [],
            'Port-Scape': [],
            'Portrait': ['Bracketed (HDR)'],
            'Peoplescape': ['Long Exposure', 'Timelapse', 'Daytime Long Expo']}

#this bit of code determines the theme of a photo idea
theme_var = random.choice(theme_list) 

#this bit of code determines the technique of a photo idea
# list comprehension generates a new list with the inappropriate techniques removed,
# without affecting the original list
technique_var = random.choice([ti for ti in technique_list if ti not in d_inappropes[theme_var]])

#this line of code determines the location of a photo idea
location_var = random.choice(location_list)

# use f-stirngs to put the whole output in a single line to keep it managable 
print(f"You should try taking a \n {theme_var} {technique_var} picture, \n from 
{location_var}.")
```

Comment: Thanks for all of your help! It turns out that the data dictionary solution is the most sensible (and powerful) one! All sorts of possibilities have opened up now. And also, thank you so much for the formatting help, I am clearly still at the early stages of learning Python.

Answer (score 1):

The issue (I think) is because you are iterating over the randomly chosen result not the list itself, you don't need the for loop that is.

```py
theme_var = random.choice(theme_list) 

if theme_var == 'Portrait':
        technique_list.remove('Bracketed (HDR)') 
print("",theme_var)

#this bit of code determines the technique of a photo idea
technique_var = random.choice(technique_list)
print("", technique_var)

print("picture, from")

#rest of the code
```

Should do it

Answer (score 0):

if I may add and give more explanation to the answers

1. You want to delete "bracked (HDR)" IF potrait is selected. Don't use .remove as it will delete "bracked (HDR)" permanently and prevent other theme to use that technique. you can use dictionary of inappropriate technique as kingfischer suggested for that
2. random.choice outputted a single value from your list. you should not use for-loop with it as for-loop will iterate over the character/alphabets in the value outputted by random.choice
3. if I may give a feedback, the indentations in your code snippet are quite jumbled. Some lines that should have indentation, don't have it. I don't know.. maybe it is unintended and the problem is with my browser. if it was so, sorry!